# SQL Server Editions: Backup restore of Enterprise Edition 2014 on Standard Edition 2017

Tags: sql-server, restore, standard-edition, enterprise-edition

I know, this kind of question has already been answered some times but I don't find some current answers and wonder if SQL Server Standard Edition 2016 SP1 has changed something in the matter as it supports all "programmability features" earlier supported by enterprise edition only.

My specific scenario is as follows:
I have got a central backup server which will be running SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition and regulary restores new backups taken from other SQL Server instances. Most instances will be on SQL Server 2017 Standard as well...however there is a Data Warehouse running SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition.

- Is it possible to restore backups taken from  a SQL Server 2014 *Enterprise Edition* instance on a SQL Server 2017 *Standard Edition* instance or could this result in an error regarding to *Enterprise Edition* features?
- Is there any way to try this out for free? SQL Server evaluation edition is equivalent to Enterprise Edition isn't it or has Microsoft now introduced a way to downgrade developer and evaluation licenses to SQL Server Standard Edition features?

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is possible to restore with same old answer that subject to condition you are not using any "enterprise specific" features. This you can get from

```
select * from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

If you are using any such feature you would have to stop using it, take fresh backup and then restore. I know its hard to tell because starting from SQL Server 2016 Sp1 standard provides far more features support. So at the last the answer would be you need to restore and test.

Good news is [SQL Server 2017 RTM Evaluation Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2017-rtm) is released so you have the Evaluation edition for your testing.

Comment: Hi Shanky, thanks for your answer. You mention Evaluation Edition. Doesn't this run Enterprise Edition under the covers and thus wouldn't complain restoring a backup with Enterprise Edition features?

Comment: @MartinGuth yep, exactly, Evaluation = Enterprise Edition, just time-limited.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2016 SP1, almost all [the enterprise features are available across all editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released). This means you shouldn't have any trouble restoring on SQL Server 2017. Note that [version downgrades still won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version) - that is, restoring a backup created on a higher version on a lower version.

> With SQL Server 2016 SP1, we are making key improvements allowing a
>   **consistent programmability surface area** for developers and
>   organizations **across SQL Server editions**.

(Yes, they changed what was included in each SKU in a service pack)